# Should a custom dimension for “Logged In” be a “Session” or “User” dimension?

Tags: google-analytics

If I define a dimension to set into GA to segment by "Guest" versus "Logged In" should that dimension be a "Session" or a "User" dimension?

More subtly, I'm interested in the transition at the point at which the user signs up, at which point we would change that dimension for that user/cookie.

From the perspective of the GA user who's using the segments, what happens to the activity, flow, goals etc of the end-user if the dimension is changed.

It seems to me that "User" is correct - but I don't understand what happens when the user moves into a new dimension.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use "Users", i do not know how did you set up tracking, and all other stuff, but assuming, that dataLayer constantly sends the data about login status. It is simply because user can during a session change a state from logged to not logged and backwards. I hope we are on the right track.